# Cannot load javascript in Chrome App

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to create my first simple chrome app, however I cannot wrap my head around how to load javascript into a page. I understand that in a chrome app, you cannot do inline javascript, but it is my understanding that you can include javascript by using the `<script src="file.js">` tags (please let me know if I have misunderstood this). I can get javascript to load fine on the first level of application navigation (index.html including the main.js file), however I able unable to get javascript to load if it is to be included in any other html pages that main.js may load (for example, main.js loading `login.html` into a `<div>`, but I cannot get `login.js` injected into `login.html`).

`manifest.json` looks like:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "short_name": "test",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "38",

  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon_16.png",
    "128": "assets/icon_128.png"
  },

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["jquery-2.1.3.min.js"]
  }]  
}
```

`background.js` looks like:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
  chrome.app.window.create(
    'index.html',
    {
      id: 'mainWindow',
      bounds: {width: 800, height: 600}
    }
  );
});
```

`index.html` looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>test</title>
      <script src="jquery.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="applicationDiv"></div>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`main.js` looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // if user isn't already logged in
  $('#applicationDiv').load('login.html');
});
```

`login.html` looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <input type="button" id="clickButton" value="Sign In"/>
      </div>
      <script src="login.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`login.js` looks like:

```
$("#clickButton").click(function() {
  console.log('in login.js');
});
```

Below are the other variations of `login.js` I have tried, but cannot get to load:

Variation 1:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  console.log('in document ready');
  $("#signinButton").click(function() {
    console.log('in login.js');
  });
});
```

Variation 2:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     var singninButton = document.getElementById('signinButton');
     // onClick's logic below:
     signinButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
         console.log('signin button pushed');
     });
 });
```

Another thing I tried was moving the `<script src="login.js"></script>` into the `<head></head>` of `login.html`, this didn't work, nor do I believe I should do that (please let me know if I'm wrong).

One other thing I did try was adding `login.js` to the content script list in the `manifest.json` file, which didn't work, and once again, I do not feel I needed to (please let me know if I'm wrong).

If someone could help me to get `login.js` loaded into the chrome app and the "Sign In" button to the point where it wrote to the console, it would be greatly appreciated! If there is any other information that is needed from me please let me know. I have no problem sharing any code as this is just me trying to learn how to create a chrome app and understand how javascript works inside of it.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can I ask why you are trying to load pages this way (through jQuery's `load`)?

Comment: @Xan, sure, and thank you for taking the time to look at my question.  I don't have a very good logical reason for using `.load()` other than I had seen it in the jQuery documentation as a way to load a new page in a `<div>`. By your comment, I'm assuming you would not recommend going this route? What would be the correct way to do this within a Chrome App? This is exactly the kind of response I was hoping for!